# C# Net core статическая память на Linux и как не нужно забывать о пробелах в имени файлов!:)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Здравствуйте господа форумчане!

Предыстория:
В районе года назад я написал некоторого чат бота и одним из его классов является некий Profiller - статический класс, который при инициализации вытягивает некоторый набор данных из файлов и формирует список профилей каналов.

Как то так:

```
public static class Profiller
{
    private static ConcurrentBag<ProfileChannel> profileChannels = new ConcurrentBag<ProfileChannel>();
    static Profiller()
    {
        LoadProfiles();
    }
    private static void LoadProfiles()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(profileChannels != null);
        Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        var filenames = Directory.GetFiles("./ProfileChannels/Commands");

        filenames.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

        foreach (var item in filenames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item));
            profileChannels.Add(FileToProfileChannel(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item)));
        }
    }
    private static ProfileChannel FileToProfileChannel(string channelname)
    {
        string[] buf;
        if (channelname != Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(templateCommandsPath))
            buf = File.ReadAllText($"./ProfileChannels/Commands/{channelname}.txt").Split(separator: new string[] { "\r\n" } , options: StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        else
            buf = File.ReadAllText($"./ProfileChannels/Commands/{channelname}.txt").Split(separator: new string[] { "\r\n" }, options: StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var dir = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var item in buf)
        {
            var m = StateReg.Match(item);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                dir.Add(m.Groups["command"].Value, int.Parse(m.Groups["value"].Value));
            }
        }

        string[] sub = File.Exists($"./ProfileChannels/SubAnswers/{channelname}.txt") ? File.ReadAllLines($"./ProfileChannels/SubAnswers/{channelname}.txt") : null;
        if(sub == null)
        {
            File.Copy(templateSubAnswersPath, $"./ProfileChannels/SubAnswers/{channelname}.txt");
            sub = File.ReadAllLines($"./ProfileChannels/SubAnswers/{channelname}.txt");
        }
        string[] resub = File.Exists($"./ProfileChannels/ResubAnswers/{channelname}.txt") ? File.ReadAllLines($"./ProfileChannels/ResubAnswers/{channelname}.txt") : null;
        if(resub == null)
        {
            File.Copy(templateResubAnswersPath, $"./ProfileChannels/ResubAnswers/{channelname}.txt");
            resub = File.ReadAllLines($"./ProfileChannels/ResubAnswers/{channelname}.txt");
        }

        string[] activities = File.Exists($"./ProfileChannels/Activities/{channelname}.txt") ? File.ReadAllLines($"./ProfileChannels/Activities/{channelname}.txt") : null;
        if (activities == null)
        {
            File.Copy(templateActivitiesPath, $"./ProfileChannels/Activities/{channelname}.txt");
            activities = File.ReadAllLines($"./ProfileChannels/Activities/{channelname}.txt");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Dir: ");
        foreach (var item in dir)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + ":" + item.Value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"channelname: {channelname}");
        Console.WriteLine("activities:");
        activities.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

        return new ProfileChannel(channelname,activities,dir["vote"],dir["advert"],dir["vkid"],dir["djid"],dir["qupdate"],dir["counter"],dir["quote"],dir["moscowtime"],dir["help"],dir["members"],dir["mystat"],dir["toplist"],dir["streamertime"],dir["music"],dir["viewers"],dir["uptime"],dir["8ball"],dir["reconnect"],dir["discord"],dir["wakeup"],dir["sleep"]) { SubAnswers = sub?.ToList(), ResubAnswers = resub?.ToList() };
    }
}
```

Под виндой это успешно работало в течение года и тут встала задача перенести этот ужас на сервер с ubuntu 16.04 lts.

Перенес все, настроил подключение и тп...

Собрал проект под .net core 2 на сервере(предварительно разумеется обновив все зависимости и тп.), в том числе протестировал это отдельно на виртуалке с Linux Mint 18.(Там все норм работает)

**Теперь про ситуацию на новом сервере с ubuntu:**

Есть некоторый класс Channel, где происходит первый вызов из статического класса:

```
 if (Profiller.GetProfileOrDefault(Name) == null)
      Profiller.TryCreateProfile(Name);
```

Итак, зная механику, любой скажет, что порядок вызова такой:
    static Profiller.Profiller
    static Profiller.GetProfileOrDefault(Name)
    ...

Но добавив в конструктор некоторый вывод, я убедился, что статический конструктор не был вызван. **Как это понимать? Возможно у net core 2.0 под linux есть отличия при вызове статики?** Поясните пожалуйста. Спасибо!

UPD: также стоит упомянуть, что методы из класс Profiller (не только эти методы) вызываются довольно часто

UPD: Добавил вывод перед 77 строкой

[image: Ошибка]
[image: Папка с файлами]
P.S Просьба не пинать за статический класс с большим кол-вом логики, я знаю что это 'дрянной стиль (еще бы кучу сингелтонов наплодил, дурак, скажите вы:)', но в данное время у меня нет желания вновь вспоминать, на чем все это завязано, со временем перепишу все с нуля.

Comment: Можно ли сократить текст вопроса до: почему не вызвался статический конструктор при запуске на linux?

Comment: А не может ли быть такого, что статический конструктор был вызван слишком _рано_? Добавьте в него логирование.

Comment: @Grundy Возможно, но я не уверен, что это даст полное понимание ситуации, может это не типичная ситуация?)

Comment: @VladD думаю нет, вывода о заходе не было, хотя лучше это вы мне расскажите)

Comment: Или возможно, у вас другой текущий каталог?

Comment: Контрольный вопрос: а `profileChannels` у вас `null` или нет?

Comment: @Xambey, просто сейчас много текста, и тяжело найти в чем именно проблема.

Comment: @VladD каталог не другой, все нормально, проверял, profileChannels не проверял, но думаю это сейчас сделаю на всякий

Comment: Могу предположить, что он прекрасно вызывается, но благополучно падает (или не падает, но выполняется, не найдя файлов в `Directory.GetFiles("./ProfileChannels/Commands");)`

Comment: @Grundy Хорошо, пожалуй немного подрежу

Comment: @Xambey если `profileChannels != null`, значит конструктор всё-таки был вызван.

Comment: Сейчас проверю и запостю результат, подождите, вас слишком много:)

Comment: @Xambey: Дело в том, что статический конструктор имеет право быть вызванным в любой момент до первого применения класса. Под .NET это может быть в сам момент первого применения, но .NET Core имеет право сделать это и в самом начале программы.

Comment: Смотрите UPD, все начинает просняться. Единственный вопрос, почему он не видит файлы, эм

Comment: @Xambey, возможно прав не хватает

Comment: @Grundy вызывается под рутом, странно

Comment: Он у вас прекрасно видит файлы. Только в строке 77 происходит ошибка. Блин, почему я могу прочесть ваш лог картинкой - а вы нет?

Comment: Итак, походу не заполняется объект dir

Comment: Таким образом, у вас на самом деле проблема с регуляркой а не со статическими конструкторами.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, уже дал ответ:) Но в какие же дебри это может завести, отличный пример неправильного парсинга файлов))

Answer (score 1):

Подведу итог, я ошибался, как и возможно, **ТЫ** читающий этот пост и думающий, что у тебя не вызывается конструктор:) Так что **нормально все с конструкторами в net core**, ищи ошибку у себя в коде, она точно есть :) Ошибка оказалась гораздо банальнее, чем думалось, **ОСТОРОЖНЕЕ С ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕМ \r\n для парсинга тестов**, в линуксе \r работает не совсем так, гуглим, все.